# nginx does not seem to load memcached module for php

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php5, memcached

I have an Ubuntu machine with nginx and memcache running, and I'm trying to use PHP with Memcached. I'm getting `Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found`.

The ini file is loaded from `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`, and all other additional .ini files are parsed, except memcached.ini (even after restarting nginx) as seen in phpinfo()'s output.

[image: output for phpinfo()]

I tried `apt-get install php5-memcache` and it completed without errors. However, `pecl install memcached` fails with the below error:

```
In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/memcached/php_memcached.h:22:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/memcached/php_memcached.c:47:
/tmp/pear/temp/memcached/php_libmemcached_compat.h:5:40: fatal error: libmemcached-1.0/memcached.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [php_memcached.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

The server has libmemcache in `/usr/include/libmemcached`, but even pecl install with `--with-libmemcache=/usr/include/libmemcached` fails.

The output for `php -i | grep -i memcache` is as below:

```
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/memcached.ini,
memcached
memcached support => enabled
libmemcached version => 0.44
Registered save handlers => files user memcached 
PWD => /usr/include/libmemcached
_SERVER["PWD"] => /usr/include/libmemcached
```

I'm not sure what else to check. Much appreciated if someone could help me out with something to fix this.

Thanks!

[UPDATE]
Memcached is working from cli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue. The only thing I had to do was restart php5-fpm 
`sudo service php5-fpm restart`.

Found this in - https://insready.com/en/blog/building-nginx-microcaching-mariadbmysql-php-fpm-debian-6-apc-memcache-drupal-7-server

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of

> php -i |grep memcache

I've used memcache for storing php sessions as well as Magento Cache & Sessions.

There are two things not to be confused with:

1. Memcached -> Note the 'd' which is a daemon listens on port no: 11211. It can be used to store php sessions instead of file system etc..
2. Memcache  -> a module usually not compiled with php. it's used when you want to store your php sessions in memcached.

so if php -i |grep memcache shows you have memcache installed. Then you need to install memcached (daemon) to be able to use/send sessions to it.

Comment: I have installed Memcached, and not Memcache - adding the output for `php -i | grep -i memcache` to my question. But again, the ini loaded here is from `php5/cli/` and for nginx is from `php5/fpm/`. I am not sure if it really matters, because the conf.d is the same.